# Groovy List grouped by Day of Date field

Tags: date, groovy, group-by

I have the following POGO class

```
public class Person{
   String name;
   Date born;

}


def persons=[] // List of person objects'
```

how to group the list by fields of type DATE. But rather, group the list by the date of birth without considering the hours, minutes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
persons.groupBy{it.born.date+'/'+(it.born.month+1)+'/'+(it.born.year+1900)}
```

the result will be a Hash map.

Suppose that `persons=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5]`

**ie:**

```
 [ '20/11/1970':[p1,p3],

   '15/09/1989':[p2,p4,p5]   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be; given a Person class:

```
public class Person {
   String name
   Date born

   String toString() {
       name
   }
}
```

We can make a list of them:

```
import groovy.time.*

def people = use( TimeCategory ) {
    [ new Person( name: 'p1', born: new Date() - 4.days ),
      new Person( name: 'p2', born: new Date() - 2.days ),
      new Person( name: 'p3', born: new Date() - 4.days ),
      new Person( name: 'p4', born: new Date() - 2.days ),
      new Person( name: 'p5', born: new Date() - 2.days ) ]
}
```

And then just use `Date.format`:

```
people.groupBy{ it.born.format( 'dd/MM/yyyy' ) }
```

If `born` is supposed to just store the Date a person was born, and not the time, you can change `Person` to:

```
public class Person {
   String name
   Date born

   void setBorn( Date born ) {
       this.born = born.clearTime()
   }

   String toString() {
       name
   }
}
```

And then you can just do:

```
people.groupBy{ it.born }
```

To get a `Map` with `Date` objects as the keys:

```
[ Sun Feb 02 00:00:00 GMT 2014:[p1, p3],
  Tue Feb 04 00:00:00 GMT 2014:[p2, p4, p5] ]
```